# Let me find the best of achieving the performance with file I/O of storing XML files

Tags: java, xml, linux

We are working with Enterprise application that involves the storing of **XML logs** to Secondary Storage as part each request processing. But it consuming more CPU time when writing logs to Secondary Storage. Thus effecting the entire application performance.

I tried to improve this with following know methods.

1. Using `ZIPInputStream` to write bytes to ***ZIP*** file. It is good in accordance to less file Size but it consumes more time than writing bytes to plain text file.
2. Using `GZIPInputStream` to write compressed bytes of data to ***GZIP*** file relatively this is also as far as performance is concerned.

So any body please suggest me the best way for achieving best performance with ***I/O*** and less in file size?

Comment: You seem to mix two things. You complain about too much CPU usage but you want to reduce I/O which is something completely different. Most of the time you have to either go for improving I/O *or* reducing CPU usage. Optimizing both at the same time is not always possible.